# varnish - multiple catch-all domain names

Tags: proxy, varnish, regex

In order to avoid setting up one backed per subdomain, I am specifying a catch-all regex string per domain name, as follows:

```
    backend domain1 {
     .host = "10.10.10.5";
     .port = "80";
 }

backend domain2 {
     .host = "10.10.10.6";
     .port = "80";
 }

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.host ~ "^(.*\.)?domain1\.com$") {
        set req.backend = domain1;
}

if (req.http.host ~ "^(.*\.)?domain2\.com$") {
        set req.backend = domain2;
}

}
```

Yet, Varnish will always show the website on the first subdomain (sub1.domain1.com) when I try to access domain2.com.

All subdomains under domain1.com load as intended.

Am I missing some parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this config:

```
backend domain1 {
     .host = "10.10.10.5";
     .port = "80";
 }

backend domain2 {
     .host = "10.10.10.6";
     .port = "80";
 }

sub vcl_recv {

if (req.http.host ~ "^(.*\.)?domain1\.com$") {
        set req.backend_hint = domain1;
}

if (req.http.host ~ "^(.*\.)?domain2\.com$") {
        set req.backend_hint = domain2;
}

}
```